# Check words in documents

Tags: python, python-2.x

Suppose you have two lists:

- One is a "dictionary", a list of words
- The other is "documents", a list of documents (which in turn, are strings)

I would check whether a dictionary's word is within a document.

```
# DOCUMENTS
doc1 = "My sister likes to have sugar, but not my father."
doc2 = "Doctors suggest that driving may cause increased stress."

documents = [doc1, doc2]

# DICTIONARY
dictionary = ["doctors", "sister", "like"]

# CHECK DOCUMENT WORDS WITHIN DICTIONARY
for word in dictionary:
    for doc in documents:
        if word in doc:
            print "\n\n\nWord:",
            print word,
            print "in document:",
            print doc
```

What's a more "pythonic" way?

Comment: How `dictionary` and `documents` variables are defined? Could you demonstrate how your program works on a sample input and what output it produces? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What if the word `'car'` is in the `dictionary`, but one of the `documents` talks about `'carpets'`? Is that an intended match?

Comment: I VTC this as broken because the `if word in doc:` doesn't check for a word within a document because of the reason [200_success](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157668/check-words-in-documents-python#comment298487_157668) mentioned above :) Due to this, the output will be different from what OP asked (e.g: `'me' in 'melt mess merry'` which returns `True` even though `me` isn't actually there)

Comment: Thank you for your comments and sorry for this late answer!
This is a very dumb code: it directly matches the words within the dictionary with the word in documents.
I added the definition of variables as asked by @alecxe.

I hope the post could be reopened.

Comment: You say in your description that " 'documents' [is] a list of documents (which in turn, are lists of words)". However, in your code each document is a string, instead of a list of words. If it actually were as you claimed, this would avoid the problem pointed out by @200_success.

Comment: You could just call `.split()` on these strings to split them into a list on whitespace (but note that the comma will be counted as part of the word in that case).

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. 
Documents are actually strings in this easy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your documents were actually lists of words, like your description said at one point, this would be way more efficient. But we can of course just make them, by using:

```
doc1 = "My sister likes to have sugar, but not my father.".split()
doc2 = "Doctors suggest that driving may cause increased stress.".split()
```

This has the problem that the punctuation gets in the way, so we need to remove it first, with one of the approaches from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) (I chose the fastest one):

```
import string
doc1 = "My sister likes to have sugar, but not my father.".translate(None, string.punctuation).split()
doc2 = "Doctors suggest that driving may cause increased stress.".translate(None, string.punctuation).split()
```

Ok, now that they are lists, we make them into `set`s, so `word in doc` becomes \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ instead of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$:

```
documents = map(set, [doc1, doc2])

# DICTIONARY
dictionary = ["doctors", "sister", "like"]

for word in dictionary:
    for doc in documents:
        if word in doc:
            print "\n\n\nWord:",
            print word,
            print "in document:",
            print doc
```

This should speed this up considerable. The most speed-up will be gained if the document strings are quite long.

The output of this is now not really understandable anymore:

```
Word: sister in document: set(['sister', 'my', 'father', 'but', 'sugar', 'to', 'likes', 'have', 'not', 'My'])
```

We can get around that by carrying around both the set and the string. I also made the splitting into words a function and used a [`if __name__ == "__main__"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to ensure this code is only run when calling it via e.g. `python script.py`, but not when doing `from script import get_words`.

```
import string

def get_words(text):
    return set(text.translate(None, string.punctuation).split())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    documents = ["My sister likes to have sugar, but not my father.",
                 "Doctors suggest that driving may cause increased stress."]

    words_in_documents = map(get_words, documents)

    for word in ["doctors", "sister", "like"]:
        for doc, words in zip(documents, words_in_documents):
            if word in words:
                print "\n\n\nWord: {} in document: {}".format(word, doc)
```